# Is it possible to speed up this join?

Tags: sql

The values table has millions of rows and doing this join on the indexes is quite slow (7s).

Is it possible to speed this up?

```
select *
from (
    select
      instance.Name, Date, Value, 
      instance.Category, instance.CreatedDate
      from ValuesTable ValuesTable
    join (
        select
          max(IDX) ID,
          CreatedDate,
          max(ModelsTable.Category) Category,
          max(InstanceTable.Name) Name,
          max(ModelsTable.Region) Country
        from InstanceTable
        join ModelsTable ModelsTable 
          on ModelsTable.ModelID = InstanceTable.ModelID
        where InstanceTable.RunCategory = 'Scenario'
          and CreatedDate = GETDATE()
        group by InstanceTable.Name, ModelsTable.Category,
          InstanceTable.CreatedDate
      ) instance on instance.ID=ValuesTable.IDX
) a
```

Comment: There is no way to optimise without knowing the dialect and the table structure. And even then, the first step is to use the `ANALYZE` / `EXPLAIN` command to see the query execution plan. Adding the execution plan to the question and tagging it with the correct DBMS will immeasurably improve its chances of being answered.

Comment: Try replacing GETDATE() with a parameter. This is a non-deterministic function and may restrict the optimizations available to the query planner. Other than that, please show us your physical database structure (including indexes).

Comment: Please prepend each column with the table where it belongs. For example, it's critical to understand which table `CreatedDate` belongs to.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would simplify the query a bit by getting rid of the first subquery.  And clarify it using table aliases:

```
select i.Name, i.Date, i.Value,  i.Category, i.CreatedDate,
       instance.id, instance.CreatedDate, instance.Category,
       instance.Name, instancy.Country
from ValuesTable i join
     (select max(IDX) as ID, CreatedDate,
             max(m.Category) as Category,
             max(i.Name) as Name,
             max(m.Region) as Country
      from InstanceTable i join
           ModelsTable m 
           on m.ModelID = i.ModelID
      where i.RunCategory = 'Scenario' and
            i.CreatedDate = GETDATE()
      group by i.Name, m.Category, i.CreatedDate
     ) instance
     on i.ID = instance.IDX;
```

Then, this is highly unlikely to do anything useful.  The problem is:

```
i.CreatedDate = GETDATE()
```

`GETDATE()` is a non-standard function.  But in every database that I know of that supports it, the function returns a time as well as a date.  You probably intend:

```
i.CreatedDate = cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

or:

```
i.CreatedDate >= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

You probably want to convert it to a date for the aggregation as well.

Then, you want indexes on:

```
InstanceTable(RunCategory, CreatedDate)
ModelsTable(ModelId)
ValuesTable(id)
```